# How to position a div at the right end of the view port?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-position, absolute

I want to position the div to the right and out of the view port. also it must be responsive. I'm just trying to add a horizontal scroll animation to the div.

Out must be like this

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="row mt-6 bg-contact align-items-center">
      <div class="col-lg-12  h-100 d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-center" id="scrollDiv">
        <h1 class="scroll-text">CONTACT US</h1>
      </div>
</div>
```

CSS: I have used bootstrap also

```
@import url("https://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/aquire");

body {
  overflow-x: hidden !important;
}

.contact-section div.row h1.scroll-text {
  font-size: 20cqi;
  font-family: "Aquire", sans-serif;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;

  -webkit-text-stroke: 3px white;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
.bg-contact {
  container-type: line-size;
  background-image: url("../assets/img/contact.png");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position-y: -11rem;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: scroll;
}
```

Comment: `position: fixed; left: 100vw;` For a better answer provide code and more information

Answer (score 0):

As I noticed you are trying to hide a menu or something outside of the screen in the right. So, instead of positioning using **right** I suggest using **left:100%** to make sure the div is always out of screen regardless of div width:

```
.rightDiv {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  width: 300px; 
  height: 100vh;
  background-color:#ff8800;
}
```

For animating div inside by clicking on Hamburger menu or something else you may use jQuery or CSS rules depending on the size of div. I suggest using css margin as the best practice:

```
$(".rightDiv").animate({"margin-left":"-300px"});
```